# How do I build an EF Core query from LINQ, then pass the query to a background job to be executed

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate, hangfire

How do I build a query from LINQ, then send to a background job to be executed? I am using EF Core with Hangfire as my background job manager.
I tried passing in an IQueryable but Hangfire can't serialize it.

I have multiple tables that can be exported in csv format. User can apply filters and sorting before exporting.

Currently the Export method builds the query, executes it, then converts the list to csv for the user to download. This is a snippet of the code:

```
        public async Task Export(GetAllVitaminDataInput input)
        {
            var query = CreateFilteredQuery(input);
            query = ApplySorting(query, input);

            var entities = await AsyncQueryableExecuter.ToListAsync(query);

            //map to dto
            var dtos = ObjectMapper.Map<List<ExportVitaminDataDto>>(entities);

            //create csv file and store on file server
            var zipFileName = _exportManager.ExportToFile(dtos.Cast<object>().ToList(), "FilePrefix");

        }
```

I would like to move this piece of code to a background job. So it compiles the query, then passes it to the background job as an argument, then it will run the export job behind.

```
        public async Task ExportBackground(GetAllVitaminDataInput input)
        {

            var query = CreateFilteredQuery(input);

            var args = new ExportVitaminDataArgs();
            args.Query = ApplySorting(query, input);

            _backgroundJobManager.Enqueue<ExportFieldDataJob, ExportVitaminDataArgs>(args);
        }
```

One reason I would like to pass in the compiled query is because I would like to make the Export background job more generic so it could be used by another other tables, by just receiving a query, then I will pass in the Object to map to, then generate the CSV.

Also I cannot Enumerate it to a list before passing it to the background job as it will get extremely slow when the number of records is large.

So my question is, how do I pass in the query, so that it can be used by the background job, to be executed, then retrieve the data to be exported into csv?

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution for this?